# How to show all related data in a one to many relation using Entity Framework?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am still coding a hotel management system in **ASP.NET MVC** and right now I am struggling in coding the room reservation module using [JavaScript Scheduler](https://javascript.daypilot.org/scheduler/).
My code is running *OK* but I do not know how to show repeated *reserved rooms* that are reserved with another name( that is what I am looking for). Here is a simple database schema I am using:

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Reservaciones()
{
    var habs = _habitacionRepository.GetList();
    return View(habs);
}
```

**HabitacionRepository.cs :**

```
public IList<Habitacion> GetList()
{
    return _context.Habitacions
            .Include(h => h.Reservas)
            .Include(h => h.CategoriaH) //ignore this
            .OrderBy(h => h.Id)
            .ToList();
}
```

**View:** (just a test)

```
@model List<HotelRestTikalShared.Models.Habitacion>
@section scripts{
<script>
@foreach ( var item in Model)
{
 var test = item.Reservas.Select(r => r.Nombres).Where(cb => item.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();

 if (item.Reservas.Count.ToString() != "0" ) //prevent from showing empty rooms that are not reserved
  {
     @: var prueba = "@test";
     @: console.log(prueba);
  }
 }

                   }
```

This is what JavaScript's console log gives me:

[image]

But I have 1 more data with the same room in the database that is not being shown (**Reservations table**):

[image]

**Tried:**
 `.SingleOrDefault()` but gives me an error: *Sequence contains more than one element*. Also tried `.Single()` and `.First()` but gives me an error: *Sequence contains no elements*.

I have to show the names of every people that have reserved the room, no matter if the room is repeated. I do not know if the mistake is in the line where says `.Where(cb => item.Id == item.Id)` but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: This does nothing `.Where(cb => item.Id == item.Id).` as you are comparing item's Id with itself. Perhaps you meant to compare a property on cb with item's Id.

Comment: I thought this was my  mistake but this worked and showed the names as expected but not the repeated rooms, perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: As written, `item.Reservas.Select(r => r.Nombres).Where(cb => item.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault()` would select the first Nombres associated with the Habitacion. (The where clause would do nothing and is ignored). If you need to show multiple people, you would need to loop through your Nombres (instead of FirstOrDefault)

Comment: Oh you are right, I removed the `.Where(cb => item.Id == item.Id).` and worked the same, umm then you mean I should open another foreach loop inside the other foreach loop?

Comment: This might be tricky and easy but I am still stuck.

Comment: Yes, so given `var test = item.Reservas.Select(r => r.Nombres).ToList()`, try doing `@foreach ( var nombre in test) ` inside your if statement, and `@: var prueba = "@nombre";` in your inner loop.

Comment: wow years of programming and I have not noticed my mistake. You are a true hero! Thanks and it worked! I wish I could mark your answer as accepted and solved.